# how to extract data from json

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

i want to extract particular values from the json object mentioned below.but it is giving some error

```
   >>> print json
{
 "response_code": 1,
 "verbose_msg": "Scan finished, scan information embedded in this object",

 "resource": "99017f6eebbac24f351415dd410d522d",
 "scan_id": "52d3df0ed60c46f336c131bf2ca454f73bafdc4b04dfa2aea80746f5ba9e6d1c-1273894724",
 "md5": "99017f6eebbac24f351415dd410d522d",
 "sha1": "4d1740485713a2ab3a4f5822a01f645fe8387f92",
 "sha256": "52d3df0ed60c46f336c131bf2ca454f73bafdc4b04dfa2aea80746f5ba9e6d1c",

 "scan_date": "2010-05-15 03:38:44",

 "positives": 40,
 "total": 40,

 "scans": {"nProtect": {"detected": true, "version": "2010-05-14.01", "result": "Trojan.Generic.3611249", "update": "20100514"},
           "CAT-QuickHeal": {"detected": true, "version": "10.00", "result": "Trojan.VB.acgy", "update": "20100514"},
           "McAfee": {"detected": true, "version": "5.400.0.1158", "result": "Generic.dx!rkx", "update": "20100515"},
           "TheHacker": {"detected": true, "version": "6.5.2.0.280", "result": "Trojan/VB.gen", "update": "20100514"},
           "VirusBuster": {"detected": true, "version": "5.0.27.0", "result": "Trojan.VB.JFDE", "update": "20100514"},
           "NOD32": {"detected": true, "version": "5115", "result": "a variant of Win32/Qhost.NTY", "update": "20100514"},
           "F-Prot": {"detected": false, "version": "4.5.1.85", "result": null, "update": "20100514"},
           "Symantec": {"detected": true, "version": "20101.1.0.89", "result": 
 "permalink": "https://www.virustotal.com/file/52d3df0ed60c46f336c131bf2ca454f73bafdc4b04dfa2aea80746f5ba9e6d1c/analysis/1273894724/"
```

and so on....
    }

to achieve above i have written following code:

```
            data = json.loads(json_post)
            response_dict = simplejson.loads(json_post)
            logging.info(response_dict)
            if response_dict['response_code'] == 0:
                self.response.out.write("11")


            elif response_dict['response_code'] == -2:
                self.response.out.write("API Request Rate Limit Exceeded<br/>")
            elif response_dict['response_code'] == -1:
                self.response.out.write("API Key provided is wrong<br/>")
            elif response_dict['response_code'] == 1:
                link.req_timestamp = response_dict['scans'][0]

                Fire_fox=response_dict.get("scans")[1].get("Firefox")
                if Fire_fox:
                    link.firefox = data['scans'][1]['Firefox']

                Trend_Micro=response_dict.get("scans")[1].get("TrendMicro")
                if Trend_Micro:
                    link.trendmicro = data['scans'][1]['TrendMicro']

                Phishtank=response_dict.get("scans")[1].get("Phishtank")
                if Phishtank:
                    link.phishtank = data['scans'][1]['Phishtank']
```

the error is KeyError: 'scans'.. plz tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: Firs of all, scans is a dict object and you are accesing to it like a list.

Comment: @jvaller  can u give me the syntactical guideline to do the same..

Comment: mcafeeVersion=response_dict["scans"]["McAfee"]["version"]

Comment: what about this line ...elif response_dict['response_code'] == 1:
                link.req_timestamp = response_dict['scans'][0]

Comment: If you want to acces to nProtect element you can do link.req_timestamp = response_dict['scans']['nProtect'] or link.req_timestamp = response_dict['scans'].items()[0]

Comment: I do not underestand you, if you want to acces to the first element of a dictionary using python you can't use the operator [0] directly, you have to convert the dictionary to a list using the dict.items() function

Comment: i want to retrieve following scans->mcfee->result's value and link.req_timestamp = scans->scan_date

Comment: If you want to acces to "scans->mcfee->result's value" you only have to do result=response_dict["scans"]["McAfee"]["result"]

Comment: link.req_timestamp = response_dict["scans"]["scan_date"]
KeyError: 'scans'
 its not working

Answer (score 1):

You should check http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

```
>>> response_dict.has_key('scans')
True
>>> response_dict["scans"].has_key(1)
False
>>> response_dict["scans"].get(1, "Not Found")
'Not Found'
>>> response_dict["scans"][1]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    response_dict["scans"][1]
KeyError: 1
```

I don't know what do you want to do from the code, but this snippets may help you:

```
for key in response_dict["scans"].keys():
    setattr(link, key.lower().replace("-","_"), response_dict["scans"][key])
```

Or:

```
for key in ["Firefox", "TrendMicro", "Phishtank", "McAfee"]:
    if scans.has_key(key):
        setattr(link, key.lower(), response_dict["scans"][key])
```

Dictionaries are so useful:

```
responses = {0:"11",
             -1:"API Key provided is wrong",
             -2:"API Request Rate Limit Exceeded<br/>"}

code = response_dict['response_code']
if responses.has_key(code):
    self.response.out.write(responses[code])
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the complexity of the json structure you are using, I would be more inclined to grab a library that makes fetching data out of this structure more easy.

Have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath-rw/1.1.2 for example.

Also you seem to often make the same mistakes ( in 2 other SO questions you have posted as well) where you try to use keys to access lists etc....   You need to work on your basic programming skills, and understand what the data structure is that you are working with.